# ng build -- prod vs ng --build aot for angular 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I am having angular 7 application and currently built the application using the command successfully

```
ng build --prod
```

My question here is that I am confused with ng build --aot vs ng build --prod. Our application is deployed on .. I havent done anything specifically to making it aot enabled but it runs successfully as well. What command do i set on the build server

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Comment: See https://angular.io/cli/build for explanations of the arguments

Comment: For Angular 7, the `aot` happens by default and you don't have to add this option specifically.

Comment: Cool. So can this command  ng build --prod be used on for other servers apart from production or is it meant only for production 

I am having angular 7 application and currently built the application using the command successfully

Comment: Do I need to add the command to my package.json file before deploying to test

Comment: @Tom the `ng build --prod` is a Angular CLI command.and No need to add anything in `package.json`

Comment: If you see the code  I have posted above it contains the ng build command

Comment: or is it command to be specified in Teamcity configuration which is used ifor deployment

Comment: When you run `ng build --aot` it will compile using the default environment but will compile the templates to JS. `ng build --prod` will apply all production build defaults and use the production environment settings. When in doubt just run `ng build --prod`.

Comment: I am confused. So running ng build --prod on Test server wont work ?

Answer (score 4):

By default angular config in angular.json like this

```
"configurations": {
              "production": {
                "fileReplacements": [
                  {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                  }
                ],
                "optimization": true,
                "outputHashing": "all",
                "sourceMap": false,
                "extractCss": true,
                "namedChunks": false,
                "aot": true
```

So aot build is enable by default so you dont need to run `ng build --aot`.

Everything is enable using `ng build --prod`